# How do I calculate average points scored by a team with a Firebase API resource in a React App?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to build a React app to calculate the average points scored of the Raptors basketball team in in it's last N home games.

Assuming that I'm using fetch (url) in the componentDidMount method and I know how to list out the Raptors score when they're the home team with:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    let url = "http://localhost:4000/games?homeTeam=Raptors"
    fetch(url)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => {
        let myGames = data.map((game, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <h3>{game.homeTeamScore}</h3>
            </div>
          )
        })
        this.setState({myGames: myGames});
      })
  }
```

and this is the JSON response for http://localhost:4000/games (I'm using json-server to mock the API response as if it was a noSQL Firebase response)

```
  "games": [{
            "id": 1,
            "date": "2019-05-21",
            "homeTeam": "Raptors",
            "awayTeam": "Bucks",
            "homeTeamPoints": 102,
            "awayTeamPoints": 110,        
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "date": "2019-05-20",
            "homeTeam": "Lakers",
            "awayTeam": "Bucks",
            "homeTeamPoints": 102,
            "awayTeamPoints": 110,        
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "date": "2019-05-19",
            "homeTeam": "Raptors",
            "awayTeam": "Warriors",
            "homeTeamPoints": 102,
            "awayTeamPoints": 110,        
        }, ... and so on
      ],
```

What is the best way for me to get the average of the Raptors points scored in their last 10 home games as of today?  What if I want the last 12 home games before a certain date (i.e. April 2, 2019)

Some options that I can think of but don't know how which approach is best is:

1. Return all Raptors home games, map only the games that I'm interested in an array then calculate the average using javascript on the client side.

Cons of this is what if I want the average of the last 1,000 Raptors home game scores.  This does not seem efficient especially if I only want a certain date range of scores.

2. Create an API resource that allows me to pass in a start date and the number of games.  The API will only return Raptors scores for N number of games before that date.  This might looks something like: http://localhost.com/teams/raptors/homeGames?sinceDate=20190402&numberGames=20

Cons of this is I'm trying to use Firebase and I'm not sure if this API resource is something that Firebase can do because I don't think Firebase allows parameters to be passed to it to specify the start date or the number of games.  Also, if I had /teams/raptors, I would have to have duplicate entries for games under /teams/[opponentTeams]

What's the best way to structure this data?  Should I do the aggregations and averages on the client side?  Is there something I can do with Google Cloud Functions that will enable more server side logic?

The right answer will be selected based on what is easiest to implement for a newbie to React and Firebase while still fulfilling the requirements above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are storing the date as an timestamp in firebase, then you can use orderby and limit to get the desired result.

```
firebase.database().ref(endpoint)
  .orderByChild('timestamp')
   .startAt(Specify the date here)
   .limit(100)
  .on('value', function(snapshot) {
   // You can get the values after the particular date and the result will be limited to first 100
 }));
});
```

Note: date should be in timestamp format not as string. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! This looks like its very close to what I'm looking for. But would you suggest that I then do the averaging calculation on the client side?  Could Firebase do the average too?

Comment: I dont think firebase has aggregation queries for calculating the average. You need to handle it on the client side.

Comment: Thanks I selected this as the correct answer because I think it will work but I'm also looking into Firebase Cloud Functions to "aggregate and summarize data periodically" https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#execute_intensive_tasks_in_the_cloud_instead_of_in_your_app